# DataTable Filter with 'n' words in a column

Tags: javascript, c#, html, datatables

I'm trying make a filter on my datatable with javascript but now I need filter one column with 'n' words

[image]

but when I use my filter it understand like one word only, but it doesn't

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var table = $('#example').DataTable({

            initComplete: function () {
                count = 0;
                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var title = this.header();
                    //replace spaces with dashes
                    title = $(title).html().replace(/[\W]/g, '-');
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select id="' + title + '" class="select2" ></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function () {
                            //Get the "text" property from each selected data
                            //regex escape the value and store in array
                            var data = $.map($(this).select2('data'), function (value, key) {
                                return value.text ? '^' + $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(value.text) + '$' : null;
                            });

                            //if no data selected use ""
                            if (data.length === 0) {
                                data = [""];
                            }

                            //join array into string with regex or (|)
                            var val = data.join('|');

                            //search for the option(s) selected
                            column
                                .search(val ? val : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });
                    //unique, tipo group by 
                    //sorte deixa em ordem abcd
                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                    });

                    //use column title as selector and placeholder
                    $('#' + title).select2({
                        multiple: true,
                        closeOnSelect: false,
                        placeholder: "Select a " + title
                    });

                    //initially clear select otherwise first option is selected
                    $('.select2').val(null).trigger('change');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <!-- Select2 plugin -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
    <!-- Select2 plugin -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left:0px !important">
        <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Demanda</th>
                    <th>Título</th>
                    <th>Solicitante</th>
                    <th>Data Inclusao</th>
                    <th>Área</th>
                    <th>SP</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th>Demanda</th>
                    <th>Título</th>
                    <th>Solicitante</th>
                    <th>Data Inclusao</th>
                    <th>Área</th>
                    <th>SP</th>

              </tfoot>
                
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh, Mykonos</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh, Londres, Paris</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York, Sao Paulo, Tokyo</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to separate witch word in a column, but it doesn't work

Comment: Your code should go in the question.

Comment: i posted at codepen https://codepen.io/rpetermann/pen/EGWmQd

Comment: SO etiquette is to show us your code and screenshots so it is easier for us to help you. It is not only polite, but sometimes our places of business do not allow access to such linked sites.

Comment: When you debug, is the value of `val` correct? If, just for testing, you skip the parsing and hard-code a known good value does it work? You can narrow down where your problem is by eliminating bad input as the cause. I'm not familiar with that jquery extension but if I'm looking at the right documentation I think you want to pass `true` for the smart search argument.